# Java class version specific naming conventions

Tags: java, naming

I have to create an Adapter between two software (mech. simulation, non-cs). Assuming we have a class named `ThatThing`. I have to handle various vendor specific implementations. These versions don't have meaningful names (unlike eclipse helios, indigo etc.).

**1. How should I name a class that should express version number?**

I find class like `ThatThing_3_6_Impl`, `ThatThing_3_7_Impl` quite awkward.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a different package name.

```
com.example.version36.ThatThing
com.example.version37.ThatThing
```

This allows you to keep all the "things" for specific versions together.

Apache Commons Lang used this format when releasing their "version 3" rewrites.

---

Since you need to be able to reference both version in a single class, I would shorten the names to:

```
ThatThing36
ThatThing37
```

In your case, this seems to be descriptive enough, and it removes the ugly `Impl` and `_`'s.

Comment: This sounds good. I'll think about it. Though in the place that these versions come together, we need to use fully-qualified name for the references, right?

Comment: How do they come together? Are you using dependency injection? Either way, to answer you question, yes.

Comment: They have many versions of data models that changes between releases. Some specific subsets of features are mixing together. No library support at all (e.g. no di, no codegen). This is history of 11 years software evolution :( .

Comment: Sad. Is it possible that by having `version37.ThatThing` extend `version36.ThatThing` would relieve some of the pain?

Comment: Unfortunately, they are structurally different and need complex transformation. It's like bitmap and vector graphic.

Comment: If you cannot group by package name, at least get rid of the underscores. `ThatThing36` is a lot nicer than `ThatThing_3_6_Impl`

Comment: @user802421 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1065/discussion-between-jeremy-heiler-and-user802421)

Comment: necro: given Java 9 (jigsaw) only being able to export packages, and expecting a single jar to be authoritative for the packages it exports, also given libraries where you may wish to split jars, so one can be compile, the other can be runtime, etc. In the latter given a library like https://immutables.github.io, where would you put the version? would it be `org.immutables.value2`, or `org.immutables2.value` in my case I'm looking at should it be `com.xenoterracide.entities2.api` and `com.xenoterracide.entities2.jpa` or `com.xenoterracide.entities.api2` and `com.xenoterracide.entities.jpa2`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter a lot.  Pick a convention that expresses everything you need it to express and stick with it.

You could use `ThatThing3_6` for "That Thing 3.6".